# why does the default constructor in MyClass calls super i.e of Object class

Tags: java, super, default-constructor

I've been working with java and learning i've a question regarding default constructor in a class. `Why does it call super (constructor of Object class.I know it does constructor chaining)?. For what reasons it is required` ?. If I define a class like this

```
MyClass 
{

    public MyClass()
       {

       }
}
```

the compiler adds super in the constructor.

```
public MyClass()
{
   super();  
}
```

P.S I've tried googling and have read Oracle Doc but couldnt find the answer .why?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every constructor must call either a different constructor of the same class or a constructor of its direct super class. The call to the super class constructor is added implicitly if you don't call it explicitly.

Since an instance of a class inherits the state of its ancestors, it must initialize it by calling the constructors of its ancestors.

In your case, your `MyClass` is a direct sub-class of `Object`, so your constructor must call the constructor of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

A class always is a chain of classes, and always ending with Object (where Object is the only exception; it has no super class).

If a new instance is created, than all the classes in the chain must be initialized, otherwise their state would be undefined. This also applies to classes that seem not to need initialization (like Object).

Initialization is done partially implicitly (variables getting their default values) and for the other part by always calling a constructor in the class.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it call super (constructor of Object class.I know it does
>   constructor chaining)?. For what reasons it is required ?

Consider this example:

```
class A {
  protected String s;
  A () {
    this.s = "hello";
  }
}

class  B extends A {
  public String get() {
    return s;// s is inherited from A
  }
}

// A's default constructor is invoked here
System.out.println(new B().get());// prints hello
```

Lets say for now java does not include the `super()` in the constructor.

```
// A's default constructor is not invoked here
System.out.println(new B().get());// prints null
```

It gives null as the default value for class types. Since A's constructor is not invoked for new instance of `B` the instance variable of `A` is not initialized.